# mysql getting data from a table if it has a value in another table

Tags: mysql

I have two mysql tables

**myTabs**

1. id
2. usercode
3. tab_id
4. fid
5. tablistid

**Tabs**

1. tab_id
2. title
3. usercode
4. access_type
5. question

both tables have tab_id as primary key and use the same value. I want to list the data from mytabs table which has same tab_id in Tabs Table and access_type = 1. I dont want to list the records from Tabs the query should only validate from Tabs if that Tab has access_type 1 then it should list

Is it possible? What I am trying is it has not returned anything.

```
 $mysql = "select  mytabs.*, tabs.* FROM mytabs, tabs  where mytabs.usercode='$usercode' and (mytabs.fid IS NULL || mytabs.fid='0') and tabs.access_type = '1' order by mytabs.tablistid asc"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `INNER JOIN`.

```
select * from tabs INNER JOIN myTabs ON tabs.tab_id = myTabs.tab_id
```

and append other condition in `where` clause.

And what INNER JOIN do is **return rows only when there is at least one row from both tables that
matches the join condition.**

Answer (score 1):

Use this query

```
SELECT * FROM Shortcut s
INNER JOIN Tabs t
ON s.tab_id=t.tab_id
WHERE t.access_type=1 AND t.usercode = '$usercode'
```